# How to access form type login/registration pop up in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access the following site and get a registration pop up. In HTML it shows as form type. I tried handling as alert but it is not and I get exception as no modal dialog box opened. I tried window handles. The size of the window handles is only 1.

Please help me, so that, I can click on 'Signin' link on registration form and then login.

Website: http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\mamtha\\Selenium Practice\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    String URL = "http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/tooltip.php";
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(URL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(3000);

Set <String> winhandle = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(winhandle.size());


    WebElement sigin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Signin']"));
    sigin.click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'username']")).sendKeys("myusername");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name = 'password']")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class = 'button']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
String URL = "http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/tooltip.php";
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(URL);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(5000);

WebElement sign=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='text_popup']/a[contains(text(),'Signin')]"));
sign.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='login']/form/fieldset[1]/input")).sendKeys("myusername");
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='login']/form/fieldset[2]/input")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='login']/form/div/div[2]/input")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Modal dialog box is getting opened in the same page itself.so, you don't want to use the window handles. You need to move the focus to the modal dialog box first and then directly access the required element(add some explicit wait condition as well).

**Working Code:**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\mamtha\\Selenium Practice\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    String URL = "http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/tooltip.php";
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(URL);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //Explicit wait is added after the Page load
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Welcome"));

    WebElement modalDialogBox=driver.findElement(By.className("fancybox-skin"));
    modalDialogBox.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Signin']")).click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("fancybox-skin")));
    WebElement loginDialogBox=driver.findElement(By.className("fancybox-skin"));

    loginDialogBox.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("myusername");
    loginDialogBox.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("987654321");
    loginDialogBox.findElement(By.className("button")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Subburaj, it worked. I am finiding hard to find the submit locator. Please see below if I am doing anything wrong.                                                                       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='button']")).click();

Comment: In login popup Dialog box , only one button is available.So, you can use the class name as locator to select the  submit button. I have updated the answer.

Comment: your xpath is correct only for the submit button. But you are finding the element using the driver instance. But, Submit button is available in the loginModaldialog box. So, you have to find the element using the loginDialogBox as reference.In case of Xpath, it should be, loginDialogBox.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@class='button']")).click().

I would strongly recommend to use the className as locator instead of XPath

Comment: @StackUser2106: Please give the upvote, If  you are satisfied with the answer.